# Delete appointments by code

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, scheduler

In my scheduler at some point I need to delete all the appointments or clear all the appointments showed in the xtrascheduler to populate it again with my custom method using a datatable.

So I need to clear the view before the load of the new appoinments. Is there something like ActiveView.Appointments.Clear()/Delete() to clear all the appointment collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this:

To simply introduce new appointments, call:

`TableAdapter.Fill`

If you want to remove all the appointments first use this code:

`SchedulerStorage.Appointments.DataSource = Nothing`

You can then set the `DataSource` to your new `BindingSource` to view a different set of appointments.